# Sending solr configs to zookeeper from hdfs using zkcli.sh bash through oozie shell action

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, oozie

I get exception below, every time i try to send solr configs to zookeeper.

As confdir I'm putting this address: "hdfs://some_address/user/Peter/dir_with_date".

In implementation in jars behind bash script i see that there is a Paths.get method, which is transforming my string with configs to one without double slashes ("hdfs:/some_ad...).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Path hdfs:/some_address/user/Peter/dir_with_date does not exist
  at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager.uploadToZK(ZkConfigManager.java:56)
  at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkConfigManager.uploadConfigDir(ZkConfigManager.java:120)
  at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI.main(ZkCLI.java:220)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is these zkcli not suitable to read data from hdfs? What's the best way to deal with such situation (building a custom jar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Manjunath, that helped. Here is exact solution:

To send solr configs to zookeeper through oozie shell action you have to copy solr config dir to worker executing this bash script by adding this into workflow

```
 <file>yourpathto/solr_config_dir#$yourpathto/solr_config_dir</file>
```

And than in bashscript you refer to this folder like this:

```
CONFIGDIR="`readlink -f solr_config_dir`"
```

Add CONFIGDIR as confdir parameter to zkcli.sh and done!

Now you have working oozie shell action that will send your solr configs to zookeeper!

Comment: Hi! After wrestling long enough with SolrJ to upload the configs, I'm trying to take this route... the one part I'm stuck on is, how are you referring to zkcli.sh in your script? I tried using the full absolute path, but it isn't finding it in the execution. Did you add zkcli.sh in your job configuration? What about the Jar dependency that script has?

Comment: Hi! I'm using oozie from cloudera and there is $CDH_SOLR_HOME variable exposed so you can grab zkcli.sh with all the jars from there ($CDH_SOLR_HOME/bin/zkcli.sh)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code of "ZkConfigManager::uploadToZK()", present here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-ranger/blob/master/ranger_solrj/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkConfigManager.java, you can observe that, the exception is happening at:

```
if (!Files.exists(rootPath))
    throw new IOException("Path " + rootPath + " does not exist");
```

It is expecting the `Path` to be a `java.nio.file.Path` and not `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` (`hdfs` path).

Since, you are passing an `hdfs` path, the exception is being thrown.

You should pass a path to the local file system (i.e. "/some_address/user/Peter/dir_with_date" should be a local file path).

Also, check this wiki, which gives an example of uploading the configuration using zkcli: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files

Comment: wonderful. I like ZkConfigManager.java link for the root cause :)